# Generate rest api code?

Tags: api, scaffolding

Is there anything out there that will generate an mvc rest api easily from existing classes or an existing database?  Seems like it wouldn't be that difficult to scaffold out various standard operations.

Comment: Last time I looked, the Java Axis2 framework will accept a WSDL file and generate a skeleton that provides both rest and soap services.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at spring roo. It allows you to reverse engineer from a database or even generate the database from entities. You should take into account a somewhat steep learning curve if haven't had any use of spring before.